# python - removing all non-numeric characters from a string inside a list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

i have a this list:

```
my_list = ['Judy 88 5', 'animal 91 5', 'Mo 86 5', 'Geno 87 6', 'exhaled 87 6']
```

i want to remove all non-numeric items from this list i.e-

```
['88 5', '91 5', '86 5', '87 6', '87 6']
```

and i want just the double digit numbers i.e -

```
['88', '91', '86', '87', '87']
```

how can i make it happen without the index being changed?
i tried using

```
my_list = [elem for elem in my_list if not any(c.isalpha() for c in elem)]
```

but it just returned me an empty list...

edit:
regex helped me on this list but what if the list was something like so:

```
my_list = ['J55udy 88 5', 'anim31al 91 5', 'Mo2 86 5', 'Geno 87 6', 'exhaled 87 6']
```

my list all ways changing but it has a constant style to it, first a user name then two digit number then a one digit number, problem is sometimes the user is using digits in his name, how can i get only the 2 digits in the middle even if the list look's like this?

```
    my_list = ['J558udy 88 5', 'anim31al 91 5', 'Mo52 86 5', 'Gen3o 87 6', 'exhaled 87 6']
```

Comment: Before writing a list comprehension, just write down line by line, what you want to have and then start putting it all together.

Comment: If the list always contains strings as shown in the example you can also use `[elem.split()[1] for elem in my_list]`.

Comment: that a good tip... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

my_list = ['Judy 88 5', 'animal 91 5', 'Mo 86 5', 'Geno 87 6', 'exhaled 87 6']
res = []
for i in my_list:
    m = re.search(r"\b(\d{2})\b", i)
    if m:
        res.append(m.group())
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['88', '91', '86', '87', '87']
```

- `\b` Regex boundaries.
- `\d{2}` Looks for int with 2 digits.

Comment: can you also explain what search does? and why are you using another list to append to?

Comment: I am using another list....just in case you do not have a value with 2 digits in it...if you are sure that all element in `my_list` has 2 digits then you can use a list comprehinsion

Comment: `my_list = [re.search(r"\b(\d{2})\b", i).group() for i in my_list]`

Comment: see my new edit to the post.. sometimes the list contains 2 digits in with the alphabet characters how to pass that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
import re
my_list = ['Judy 88 5', 'animal 91 5', 'Mo 86 5', 'Geno 87 6', 'exhaled 87 6']
regex = re.compile(r'\b\d\d\b')
my_list = [regex.search(i).group() for i in my_list]
```

`my_list` would become:

```
['88', '91', '86', '87', '87']
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is indeed a good solution, but it can also be achieved without. The solution below will find all the double digits number in the strings, even if you have multiple instance, like: `'blabla 88 5 63'`.

```
my_list = ['Judy 88 5', 'animal 91 5', 'Mo 86 5', 'Geno 87 6', 'exhaled 87 6']
digits = "123456789"
new_list = []

for elt in my_list:
    for k, l in enumerate(elt):
        if l in digits and k!= len(elt)-1 and elt[k+1] in digits:
            new_str = elt[k:k+2]
            new_list.append(new_str)
```

It can be turned into a one liner:

```
digits = "123456789"
[elt[k:k+2] for elt in my_list for k, l in enumerate(elt) if l in digits and k!= len(elt)-1 and elt[k+1] in digits]
Out[37]: ['88', '91', '86', '87', '87']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use regular expression to extract the numeric strings.

```
import re

my_list = ['Judy 88 5', 'animal 91 5', 'Mo 86 5', 'Geno 87 6', 'exhaled 87 6']
nums = [re.search('\d+', lst).group(0) for lst in my_list]
print(nums)
```

Output

```
['88', '91', '86', '87', '87']
[Finished in 0.1s]
```